# How to for loop in casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to click a 'next' button N number of times and grab the page source each time.  I understand that I can run an arbitrary function on the remote website, so instead of click() I just use the remote function nextPage()  How do I run the following, an arbitrary number of times:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://www.example.com', function() {

    this.echo(this.getHTML());
    this.echo('-------------------------');

    var numTimes = 4, count = 2;

    casper.repeat(numTimes, function() {
        this.thenEvaluate(function() {
            nextPage(++count);
        });

        this.then(function() {
            this.echo(this.getHTML());
            this.echo('-------------------------');
        });
    });

});
```

'i' here is an index I *tried* to use in a javascript for loop.

So tl;dr: I want lick 'next', print pages source, click 'next', print page source, click 'next'... continue that N number of times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you can pass a value to the remote page context (i.e. to `thenEvaluate` function like this:

```
    this.thenEvaluate(function(remoteCount) {
        nextPage(remoteCount);
    }, ++count);
```

However, `Casper#repeat` might not be a good function to use here as the loop would NOT wait for each page load and then capture the content.

You may rather devise a event based chaining.

The work-flow of the code would be:

1. Have a global variable (or at-least a variable accessible to the functions mentioned below) to store the `count` and the `limit`.
2. listen to the [`load.finished`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#load-finished) event and grab the HTML here and then call the next page.

A simplified code can be:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var limit = 5, count = 1;

casper.on('load.finished', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        this.echo ("Failed to load page.");
    }
    else {
        this.echo(this.getHTML());
        this.echo('-------------------------');
    }



    if(++count > limit) {
        this.echo ("Finished!");

    }
    else {
        this.evaluate(function(remoteCount) {
            nextPage(remoteCount);
            // [Edit the line below was added later]
            console.log(remoteCount);
            return remoteCount;
        }, count);

    }

});

casper.start('http://www.example.com').run();
```

> NOTE: If you pages with high load of JS processes etc. you may also want to add a `wait` before calling the nextPage :

```
this.wait( 
   1000, // in ms
   function () {
        this.evaluate(function(remoteCount) {
            nextPage(remoteCount);
        }, count);
   }
);
```

> [EDIT ADDED] The following event listeners will help you debug.

```
// help is tracing page's console.log 
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) { 
    console.log('[Remote Page] ' + msg); 
}); 

// Print out all the error messages from the web page 
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) { 
    casper.echo("[Remote Page Error] " + msg, "ERROR"); 
    casper.echo("[Remote Error trace] " + JSON.stringify(trace, undefined, 4)); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your code sudipto.  I am ALMOST there, just one strange problem.  It works for every page but the second one.  It seems as if the nextPage function has a null for the first iteration INSIDE the evaluate function?  I'm not sure what's going on.  But here's the code:
http://pastebin.com/QJvA2nap
 and here's teh output: http://pastebin.com/kKZHiLKM

Comment: ok. First add these 2 event listeners:

    `// help is tracing page's console.log
    casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
        console.log('[Remote Page] ' + msg);
    });`

    `// Print out all the error messages from the web page
    casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
        casper.echo("[Remote Page Error] " + msg, "ERROR");
        casper.echo("[Remote Error trace] " + JSON.stringify(trace, undefined, 4));
    });`

Comment: The above 2 event listeners will listen to remote page errors and console.log called through JS in remote page (you can call this from the `evaluate` function. Now, in the `evaluate` function, before you are writing `return remoteCount;` add  this line `console.log(remoteCount);`. This will show the value received directly from the page. In case this also does the same, we need to dig deeper.

Comment: So it appears that the errors are the same from console in a browser, but it looks like the page I'm trying to access does a refresh to generate a unique identifier for the session (or day, or user, or browser, not sure) and appends it to the url.  This reload/refresh causes your code to be unable to call nextPage(), because, I assume, it doesn't exist on the intital load, not sure.  Either way, but iterating from 0 instead of 1, I can get all the data, I need. THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [`Casper#repeat`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#repeat)

This should do, for the most part, what you want:

```js
var numTimes = 10, count = 1;

casper.repeat(numTimes, function() {
    this.thenEvaluate(function(count) {
        nextPage(count);
    }, ++count);

    this.then(function() {
        this.echo(this.getHTML());
        this.echo('-------------------------');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your help.  I've tried to adjust your page to my script, but I still cant get it to go to the different pages, it outputs the same page each time. It appears that nextPage(++count) does not fire.  However nextPage(5) does fire.  It appears that I can't pass variables to the thenEvaluate function, ive been trying for an hour to find out how. Maybe this is my lack of javascript knowledge, but no combination seems to work for me.

Comment: @hedix: the variable `count` used inside evaluate should be present in remote page scope or passed as param through evaluate function.

Comment: @sudipto Yea, it looks like I forgot to pass it through as an argument. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
var global_page_links = [];

casper.then(function(){
    for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){    
        // you just add all your links to array, and use it in casper.each()
        global_page_links.push(YOUR_LINK);
    }

    this.each(global_page_links, function(self, link) {
        if (link){
            self.thenOpen(link, function() {
                console.log("OPENED: "+this.getCurrentUrl());
                // do here what you need, evaluate() etc.
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is answer to question, how to use for() in casperjs to launch several links